# How would I use Selenium to select a drop-down menu

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I'm trying to use selenium to select a drop-down menu in python. This is the HTML of the website in question.

```
<select data-id="1388874259461-k9k0y" name="walletselectedbitcoin" id="selectWallet" class="medium hidden-field">
    <option value="trading">trading</option>
    <option value="deposit">deposit</option>
    <option value="exchange">exchange</option>
</select>
<div data-id="1388874259461-k9k0y" class="custom dropdown medium">
    <a href="#" class="current">trading</a>
    <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">trading</li>
        <li class="">deposit</li>
        <li class="">exchange</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<label for="orderType">Select Wallet</label>
```

I'm trying to change the `<li class="selected">trading</li>` to the exchange class below it so that the trading is not selected and the exchange is selected.

Here's what I have so far. It doesn't seem to work.

```
two = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section/div/div/form/div[2]/div')
for option in two.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'exchange':
        option.click()
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Can you explain the actual error?  Do you get the element you expected in `two`.  Is the list of options empty so that the for loop never executes?  Are you positive that the `if` condition is satisfied.

Comment: It doens't select the exchange option. It stays at trading, and the program closes without selecting the drop-down. Is there a way to use send_keys to change where 'selected' is written?

Comment: So you are confirming that `option.click()` actually executes and nothing happens?  Thanks for the clarification.  Also, what is the website?

Comment: It executes and  nothing happens. The website is https://www.bitfinex.com/account/withdraw . You have to log in and click withdraw. I want to change the drop down menu from trading to exchange.

Comment: I've only used selenium in java but it seems that also in python you need [Action chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) to operate on selects.

Comment: I didn't get your point clearly, but if you want to select the `option` tag which has `exchange` as `text`, try this: `next(el for el in driver.find_element_by_id_('selectWallet').find_elements_by_tag_name('option') if el.text == 'exchange').click()`

Comment: Otherwise if you want to change `<li class="selected">trading</li>` and `<li class="">exchange</li>` to `<li class="">trading</li>` and `<li class="selected">exchange</li>` respectively, you should use `execute_script`.

Comment: So you can try these lines: `driver.execute_script('var elArray=document.getElementByClassName("custom dropdown medium").getElementByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li");for el in elArray: if el.innerHTML=="trading": el.setAttribute("class", "");'); driver.execute_script('var elArray=document.getElementByClassName("custom dropdown medium").getElementByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li");for el in elArray: if el.innerHTML=="exchange": el.setAttribute("class", "selected");');`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was send_keys. Like so:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/a').send_keys('exchange')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/section/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/a').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Also, the dropdown menu had to be visible before it could be worked on. I used:-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.selector").click()
```

The answers above also work.